# Can 'menu' be used as a 'catalog'?

Tags: word-usage, informal-language

The word 'menu' as we all know is mostly used to list the food items in a restaurant. It is also used in computers where we have a 'drop down' lists.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/menu) gives an example of...

> *a menu of television programs*

I wonder whether we can use this word instead of 'catalog' or the like.

Say...

> Here's our menu card listing all *pieces of furniture* we sell

Answer (score 4):

No, you would be better off sticking with *catalog* (or perhaps *inventory* in your example.) I realize that catalog is normally assumed to have multiple pages, so if you can list the entire available furniture on one card, you might call it a *stock list*.  if the card includes prices, you could call it a *price list*.

Comment: I have visited many restaurants that have a menu in fact of 10 pages!